# SSIS ScriptTask Not Executing

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I'm seeing some very strange behaviour when building and running a SSIS Package in Visual Studio:

I have a Script Task that only executes when the containing DataFlow has no Predecessor or I have a break point in my script.

If, the Script Task is simply ignored, all Columns created by the Script Task are NULL.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful here.  Also, are you saying the script task is completely skipped over without ever going to yellow in debug?

Comment: When you place the breakpoint in your script task, do you step through your code? Is it behaving as intended?

Comment: Questions about code that show no code are rather difficult ti diagnose

Comment: What you are describing does not happen.   There is something about what is happening that you are leaving out of the description.

Comment: Do you mean Script Task or Script Component? Script Task exists in the control flow and Script Component exists in data flow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, because i coppied some of the Script Tasks they had the same ID.

Recreating the script task fixed the problem for me.